# haystack SearchQueryResult object returns multiple objects

Tags: django-haystack, searchqueryset

I don't get why get() with pk=1 would result in multiple objects returned below..

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(self)

for obj in sqs:
      do something with obj.object # obj.object results in error
```

get() returned more than one MyModel -- it returned 4! Lookup parameters were {'pk': u'1'}

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are looking for, may be we can work on solution then ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I was having the same problem, the following gave me `MultipleObjectReturned` error:

```
context['object_list'] = [result.object for result in results]


lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/models.py", line 80, in _get_object
self._object = self.searchindex.read_queryset().get(pk=self.pk)
```

instead of referencing the `obj.object` directly, I worked around with using pk

```
context['object_list'] = Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=[result.pk for result in results])
```